# VB Visual Studio - .xlsx resource file not updating at compile time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resources, resource-files

I include a .xlsx file as one of my project resources. If i edit this file in the projectName\Resources folder, the updates do not register when I compile the project and it only uses the state of the resource when I first added it.

Normally I would just re-add the resource but this project will eventually be compiled over the command line without the use of the IDE.

Comment: why are you using  .xlsx file as  project resource? it has a lot of disadvantages. why not to use binary file?

Comment: For compatibility mostly, There's an existing vba app that exports it's findings to an excel file of ~15'000 entries. I'm creating a UI application in vb that loads this file and allows processing and sorting of the findings. I could probably get it changed to a .csv instead if that's better? but that's about as much freedom as I have in the regard.